# Updating a column which has multiple rows with uniqueidentifier value

Tags: sql-server, database

Let me begin with an apology as it may be a dumb question. I am supposed to `UPDATE` a column which is of `uniqueidentifier` datatype, say the table columns are (id, username, pwd, Uuid) where `Uuid` is the `uniqueidentifier` column.

This `Uuid` column has multiple null values. I am supposed to update this by generating v1 version of uuid from external stored procedure.

I tried something like the below code, but it doesn't work. (GetOptimizedUuid SP generates V1 Uuid)

```
DECLARE @no INT;
DECLARE @i INT;

SET @no = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table1)

SET @i = 0;

WHILE @i < @no  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempUuid TABLE (SeqUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
                             OptimizedUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

    INSERT INTO @TempUuid
        EXECUTE [dbo].[GetOptimizedUuid]

    UPDATE table1  
    SET Uuid = (SELECT OptimizedUuid 
                FROM @TempUuid) 
    WHERE Uuid IS NULL AND LIMIT 1, @no;

    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

If it has 7 records and only 2 records having Uuid value, how do I update so that remaining 5 Uuid records having different value? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you also share inside of GetOptimizedUuid procedure?

Comment: @SerkanArslan I am not supposed update because of my company policy, it just returns two varients of uuid's, one is the generated one and the other one is optimized for additional security.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @affectedrows INT;

SET @affectedrows = 1;

WHILE @affectedrows > 0  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempUuid TABLE (SeqUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
                             OptimizedUuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

    INSERT INTO @TempUuid
        EXECUTE [dbo].[GetOptimizedUuid]

    UPDATE TOP(1) table1  
    SET Uuid = (SELECT TOP 1 OptimizedUuid 
                FROM @TempUuid) 
    WHERE Uuid IS NULL 

    SET @effectedeows = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Comment: it is just updating one record per execution and throwing this error : 

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The statement has been terminated.

Any way to fix it?